# Implementing Google Spaces

Tags: java, api, autocomplete

I am trying to add an autocomplete option for a place name (and, if possible, address, website of the place) to my application form but I can't get it to load as an autocomplete.

```
<script>
var geocoder;
   var map;
   function initialize() {  
   var input = document.getElementById('id_address');
   var options = {
types: ['address'],
componentRestrictions: {
  country: 'in'
 }
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
    if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
      document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;

alert(place.address_components[i].long_name);

    }
  }
}
})
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```